# Extract sequence fragments from FASTA file using coordinates on a GRanges object

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I need to extract the intergenic sequences of Bacillus Subtilis.

I have the full DNA sequence of B.subtilis in R, imported with seqinr.
I imported the dna sequence into R using the function read.fasta of the package seqinr;

I then created a GRanges object from Bacillus subtilis genbank file using the package "genbankr" to extract intergenic coordinates.

This is the format of my GRanges Object with intergenic coordinates:

```
GRanges object with 3841 ranges and 1 metadata column:
  seqnames             ranges strand |             intergenic_id
     <Rle>          <IRanges>  <Rle> |               <character>
  168      168       [   1,  409]      * | intergenic_SEQ-BEGIN_dnaA
  168      168       [1751, 1938]      * |      intergenic_dnaA_dnaN
  168      168       [3076, 3205]      * |      intergenic_dnaN_yaaA
  168      168       [3422, 3436]      * |      intergenic_yaaA_recF
  168      168       [4550, 4566]      * |      intergenic_recF_yaaB
  ...      ...                ...    ... .                       ...
```

Therefore in R I have:
 "x" (the full DNA sequence imported with seqinr) and "intergenic" (the GRanges Object with coordinates)

I have seen people asking similar question in this forum, I have tried to follow those answers unsuccessfully by using a variety of packages but I can't figure it out. I am hopeful there is a easy solution for this; any help is appreciated.

My desired output would be to produce a fasta file with the intergenic sequences in the following format:

```
>intergenic_SEQ-BEGIN_dnaA
ATATATATATTATTTATTTTTTTTTTTTATTATAT
>intergenic_dnaA_dnaN
ATATATCGCGTCGATCTAGACTCAGGCATG
etc.
```

Basically a line with the name of the intergenic sequence taken from the intergenic_id name column of my GRanges object followed by the sequence extracted from the fasta using the coordinates in the GRanges.

NOTE: in the desired output i just typed some random sequences, just as example.

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132118/how-can-i-extract-sequences-from-a-fasta-file-for-each-of-the-intervals-defined) that uses `BSGenome::getSeq` which can take as input a `BSGenome` object and a `GRanges` object.

Comment: I tried that way, but the problem is I can not find a BSGenome object available for my organism. I have a FASTA. organism is Bacillus Subtilis strain 168.

Comment: Try reading your fasta file using the `readDNAStringSet` function from `Biostrings`, before passing the `DNAStringSet` object along with the `GRanges` object to `getSeq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think BSGenome it is the best way (you can build your [BSgenome](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJy4ye75_UAhUPU1AKHWsID00QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bioconductor.org%2Fpackages%2Fdevel%2Fbioc%2Fvignettes%2FBSgenome%2Finst%2Fdoc%2FBSgenomeForge.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEw1HbH_E6dXBFo2wQPy2atlCli3g&sig2=00YWZ1n-1m5-8ixCJrDYEw)), but you can also do it with seqinr creating your own function:

```
require('seqinr')
require('GenomicRanges')

# Create objects
mygenome <- read.fasta('sequence.fasta')[[1]] # I assume it is just one chromosome
mygrs <- GRanges(seqnames=rep('NC_000964',3),
                 ranges=IRanges(c(1,50,100),c(20,55,103)),
                  strand=c('*','*','*'))
mcols(mygrs)$Gene <- c('GenA','GenB','GenC')
mygrs
# GRanges object with 3 ranges and 1 metadata column:
#   seqnames     ranges strand |        Gene
# <Rle>  <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character>
#   [1] NC_000964 [  1,  20]      * |        GenA
# [2] NC_000964 [ 50,  55]      * |        GenB

# Function to subset the seqinr list
 extractSeq <- function(x) {
    if (as.character(strand(x)) == '-') {
      comp(mygenome[end(x):start(x)])
    } else {
      mygenome[start(x):end(x)]
    }
  }    

# Ex
  extractSeq(mygrs[1])
  #  [1] "a" "t" "c" "t" "t" "t" "t" "t" "c" "g" "g" "c" "t" "t" "t" "t" "t" "t" "t" "a"    

# Apply to all
  myseqs <- lapply(mygrs, extractSeq)

# write to a file
  write.fasta(myseqs, mcols(mygrs)$Gene, 'myfile.fa')
```

Comment: I will try your code tomorrow but by reading it seems like it could be my solution; I also already have those packages seqinr and genomic ranges. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This works perfectly however I realized there is a problem in the intergenic function of genbankr; my intergenic ranges, as you can see from the snap in my post, are all classed as *, no plus or minus. Therefore using this method I end up only with forward strand sequences. Working on sorting this out; I have tried other methods, such has gaps from GenomicFeatures; but all have downsights.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve, but it kinda makes sense that the intergenic regions have no strand, since it is just regions between annotated genes.

Comment: I would like to extract the intergenic region upstream of each gene. So if for example 2 genes follow each other, first gene on the reverse strand and second gene on the forward strand. The intergenic region is shared by the 2 genes. For the first gene, which is on the reverse, the intergenic region would be the reverse complement of the intergenic region; for the second gene, which is on the forward strand, it is that intergenic region.    My method instead for this covergent regions only report them once only saying that it is between those 2 genes.

Comment: Essentially I would like to treat the intergenic regions as regions upstream of each gene.

Comment: It does not seem a trivial thing for a comment and it is a bit off topic. Don't know if it is better to open a question. Anyways, if it helps, the `gap` function of GRanges seems to consider and conserve the strandness.

Comment: Yes I tried that but it does not create a meta data column with the names for the intergenic sequence. It does have strand information though, but I need names of the gene it refers too. Many thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `flank` to retrieve a region of certain length upstream each grange (kinda the promoter). Then, find the overlaps with the gaps object to annotate the gaps. Good luck

Comment: Sorted. After failing to do what I wanted trying all these methods I made my own perl script to parse and do this type of extraction from a genbank file and return me the appropriate FASTA with the sequences without Bioperl. Still surprised I did not find anything to do this.