# transformation of csv file with dna sequences to fasta format with rstudio and with biostrings

Tags: r, csv, transform, fasta, dna-sequence

i have a csv file with DNA sequences. The file has 4 columns which are the name of the chromosome, the start and end of the sequence  and the strand (missing or +). I want to transorme this file in fasta format with Rstudio and with the tool of biostring. But i don't know much about the code whick i have to use. First i download the library of biostring.
i use this code:
c

```
sv = read.csv("foo.csv")
   fa = character(4 * nrow(csv))
   fa[c(TRUE, FALSE)] = sprintf("> %s", csv$chr)
   fa[c(FALSE, TRUE)] = csv$seq
   writeLines(fa, "foo.fasta")
library(Biostrings)
    seq = csv$seq
    names(seq) = csv$id
    dna = DNAStringSet(seq)
    write.XStringSet(dna, "foo.fasta").
```

also when i run the code: `fa[c(TRUE, FALSE)] = sprintf("> %s", csv$chr)`, it appears ---`Error in fa[c(TRUE, FALSE)] = sprintf("> %s", csv$chr) :`
replacement has length zero
do you reccomend me some other code? or what should change in this code.
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract sequence fragments from FASTA file using coordinates on a GRanges object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333936/extract-sequence-fragments-from-fasta-file-using-coordinates-on-a-granges-object)

Comment: You state the `.csv` file has 4 columns: chromosome, start, end, and stand. Where is the sequence itself? Otherwise, we'd need to know the organism and assembly to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind not using R to achieve your goal. You can look at `bedtools getfasta` ([documentation](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/getfasta.html)) for a command-line solution in Linux.

The usage of is quite simple:

```
bedtools getfasta -fi yourFasta.fa -bed foo.bed -s
```

`-s` option for force strandness.

But first you may need to convert your csv `foo.csv` to a bed format. You can do this in R also:

```
library(reader)
df <- read_csv("foo.csv")
write_tsv(df, "foo.bed", col_names=FALSE)
```